# Do fault codes get recorded with a date stamp into a log with a history of DTCs?

Tags: obd-ii, dtc

If it's relevant, I'm asking this question about a 2006 Lexus GS300. A previous post asked if a fault code leaves a time stamp, and the answer was "no." I want to know if fault codes have a date stored in the metadata. I only need to go back a few months. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! .

Answer (score 1):

The OBDII standard does not specify either a date or a time to be attached to the fault codes.

While it's certainly possible that a given manufacturer might store timestamps with fault codes internally, those codes would potentially be available only to manufacturer-specific diagnostic tools or perhaps some third-party tools that have either cracked the system or have licensed the technology from the manufacturer.

Another problem with this idea is that many cars really don't know what date/time is current, at least not 2006 vintage.  Some of the newer "connected" cars do but that's a more recent development.

Comment: Thank you Paulster2 for answering my question. I have a follow-up question: Do fault codes provide a mileage stamp, or some other way to calculate the distance travelled between occurrences of fault codes?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained what you are trying to accomplish here.  But in answer to your follow-up, NO, I don't believe mileage is included either.  The fault is recorded and that's it.  Keep in mind that OBDII was implemented in 1994 and was designed in the early 1990's, so it's not going to reflect 2020's technology.  Again, SOME manufacturers may implement additional data logging for SOME models but OBDII is not going to support it directly.  Manufacturers can and do have proprietary extensions and some of those may have what you're asking for.

Comment: I know from experience that some vehicles do record the number of ignition cycles since a given fault, which I found very interesting when a service department told me this. It's been a while so I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this was on an original version Nissan Versa. I don't know if a Lexus would have similar info